# How can I determine if the mouse is over a specific view in NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsview, nstableviewcell

I have an NSTableView that is displaying different views for each cell. How can I determine that my mouse is over a specific view? I want to be able to hide/show certain UI pieces depending on the mouseover.

Comment: What do you mean by "view"? Do you mean how can you tell if the mouse is over the table view or if it's over a row/column/cell in the table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking you'd use an [NSTrackingArea](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/Reference/Reference.html).